# How to nest countif into if?

Tags: excel, if-statement

`=IF(J7 = "x"; (COUNTIF(E:E;E1)>1)); 1)`

I would like to see if column J contains x or not and if yes check the numbers in column e, not to be able to put down the same number twice!

So I have 20 doors, and if a door is used we put down an x. I don't want to be able to use the same doors twice, but rather only use the door only if it hasn't already been used!

Comment: what is `ifcount` ?

Comment: sorry countif, i unfortunatly have to use excel in hungarian- i changed taht

Comment: Can you explain what should happen if E1 is found more than once?

Comment: i try my best! We have lets say five 70 doors. the administrator fill in an excel and if somebodey uses a door he puts down and x into an excel and puts down the door number as well, in the same row. Now if a door is not used anymore the x will be deleted. And the door can be reassigned. there is no time to manually check if a door is in use or not. So i made a conditional formatting checking if the same door number is used twice, if it is used twice the both cells will turn red. but i want it only to turn red if the door is marked with x(it is in use).

Comment: If you're using CF, perhaps `=and(J7 = "x"; countif(E:E;E1)>1)` ? Not sure why you're referencing J7 and E1.